# How we can change this sentence into passive : " I am happy. "

Tags: passive-voice

I'm happy .
The anovel sentence how we can change it into passive

Comment: You can't.  To be put in the passive, a sentence must have an object, and "I'm happy" does not have an object.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of making it passive:

> Happiness is felt by me.

---

**Update**: A comment has said that *feeling* happy is not the same thing as *being* happy.

But emotions are felt, by definition.

Consider this:

> I **am** happiness.

Nobody would ever say that.

When you *are* happy you are *feeling* happy:

> I am happy.
>   I am feeling happy.

Aside from the meaning that doesn't make sense, I can think of no interpretation where these two sentences don't mean exactly the same thing.

---

While it's true from a *strictly syntactical* point of view that mine is not a passive version of the verb *to be*, it's not at all true that it's not a passive version of *I am happy* that means the same thing.

Comment: @stangdon I don't agree that the definition is that a past participle must be used. A passive construction just means that the subject in the sentence is not the agent of an action. However, I have modified my example because I realized that it wasn't correct even at that broader level . . .

Comment: [Using the past participle is absolutely, 100% part of the definition of what the passive voice is.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/active-and-passive-voice)  Your example sentence is now *a* passive construction, but I wouldn't call it a passive version of the original sentence, because it's changed the verb from *to be* to *to feel*.  It's kind of conceptually the same, I agree, but not quite the same thing.  (As a thought experiment, what if the sentence were "I am tall"?)

Comment: @stangdon I agree with you only in an extremely literal sense. I would have answered as such if the question had been to make that specific verb passive. But aside from an isolated thought experiment where it would not be strictly correct, my answer is in the passive and its meaning is the same.